# switching between a gif and a png on a JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, animated-gif, imageicon

I'm trying to make a Russian Roulette game and I'm trying to change the `JLabel` to the gif of the revolver spinning. However, I can change it from the gif but not back to the picture of the revolver. Or is there a way to play the gif only once and have it stop then change it to another gif?

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class RussianRoulette extends JFrame {

    private int Chamber;
    private int BulletPos;
    private boolean ButtonToggle;
    JButton Fire = new JButton("Fire");
    JButton Spin = new JButton("Spin");
    JLabel Gun = new JLabel();
    public RussianRoulette() {
    ButtonToggle = true;
    Chamber = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);
    BulletPos = 0;
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    Gun.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 375);
    Fire.setBounds(25, 375, 100, 100);
    Spin.setBounds(350, 375, 100, 100);
    ImageIcon imgThisImg = new ImageIcon("Revolver2.png");
    Gun.setIcon(imgThisImg);                
    Spin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                spinGun();
                sleep(600);

            }
        });

        Fire.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                fireGun();
            }
        });
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(Gun);
        frame.add(Fire);
        frame.add(Spin);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        Image im = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("icon.png");
        frame.setIconImage(im);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setTitle("Russian Roulette");

    }

    public void spinGun() {
         ImageIcon imgThisImg = new ImageIcon("SpinRevolver.gif");
         Gun.setIcon(imgThisImg);
         sleep(600);
        AudioPlayer player3 = new AudioPlayer("Spin.wav");
        player3.play();
        BulletPos = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);
    }

    public void fireGun() {

        if (ButtonToggle == false) {
            AudioPlayer player5 = new AudioPlayer("Click.wav");
            player5.play();
        }

        if (Chamber == BulletPos && ButtonToggle == true) {
            AudioPlayer player2 = new AudioPlayer("Shot.wav");
            player2.play();
            ButtonToggle = false;
        } else {
            Chamber++;
            CheckNum();
            AudioPlayer player = new AudioPlayer("Click.wav");
            player.play();
        }
    }

    public void CheckNum() {
        if (Chamber > 6) {
            Chamber = 1;
        }
    }

    public void reload()
    {
        //play reload animation
        ButtonToggle = true;
    }

        public void sleep(int ammount)
        {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(ammount);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

}
```

Comment: An actual [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would involve less guess work and better responses

Comment: Poor choice for a game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, based on feedback, you want the animation to start running on a button click and stop automatically after a given period of time...

Probably the simplest solution would be to use a `javax.swing.Timer`, otherwise you'll need to set yourself up as some kind of `ImageObserver` and interrupt the various events coming from the image...like I said, simpler...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class SpiningLabel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpiningLabel();
    }

    public SpiningLabel() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private ImageIcon spin;
        private ImageIcon still;

        private JLabel label;
        private Timer timer;
        private JButton button;

        public TestPane() {
            spin = new ImageIcon("spin.gif");
            still = new ImageIcon("still.png");

            label = new JLabel(still);
            button = new JButton("Allons-y!");
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    label.setIcon(spin);
                    button.setEnabled(false);
                    timer.restart();
                }
            });
            timer = new Timer(2000, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    label.setIcon(still);
                    button.setEnabled(true);
                }
            });
            timer.setRepeats(false);

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(label);
            add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: i have updated my code to include my whole class but let me rephrase myself. So when I press the Spin button my Jlabel will be replaced with the gif of the revolver spinning then change back to the still picture but with only on button click. /)

Comment: @user3307676 So, you want some kind of timed event?

Comment: Thank you for the help! /) Geronimo!